# Replace JTextField with a line in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I want to replace

[image]

with this

[image]

Is it possible in Java Swing? Maybe there is some UI library for this?

Comment: Try - https://github.com/mgarin/weblaf. It has PainterFactory that you can use to get the background painted in black. You should be able to do in plain java swing as well, by using a painter.

Comment: Read about [look-n-feels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) in Java

Comment: Thankyou! it still doesnt get me that underline textbox but you helped me found a useful library which i'm going to use in my current project. @sethu

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any additional library. Just set the `JTextField` properties and set a `Border`

```
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
    textField.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    textField.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.GRAY));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it this way, 
add a `jlabel` to the `jframe` and add the `jtextfield` over the `jlabel`
then call

```
 label.setvisible(false); 
 textfield.setvisible(true);
```

setting `setvisible(false)`  will hide the component.and whenever you need to show the line

```
 label.setvisible(true); 
 textfield.setvisible(false);
```